# Client reduced pay rate on 3rd day of joining as a IT contractor

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process, recruitment, united-states, contractors

I am an international student, faced a very rough job search days and finally got placed as a Developer.

Three companies involved here: A, B and C.

A interviewed and selected me but asked to come through B, who in-turn asked me to come through C. I am a full-time employee of C now, working at A's location.

The only document I signed till date is the offer letter from 'C'.
I was offered $50/hour at first but on 3rd day of joining I receive this one-liner email from company B saying "*Have received billing rate concerns. Will let you know*". Company 'C' comments as : "*We are still not aware of new rate but it might go down to $35/hr. Either have a job with lower rate or no job at all.*"

I did share my offer letter with A's supervisor before joining. Could this be the reason for my sudden payrate change ?

Should I raise a concern? **How** and **to whom** should I raise concern to ?

I don't want to get into bad talks in the start of my career!

P.S.: A and B both are major employers, like in the IV league of IT companies.

Comment: I would strongly advise against "just accepting it". I suggest asking a responsible manager in B first. Then validate their statement with your supervisor at A. Regardless of those answers, I suggest starting this 4-6 week process ASAP, even while being employed at C. 4-6 weeks is not THAT long time and the difference in pay may be relevant later on.

Comment: Also, how could they not be aware and at the same time, say it might go down? This would mean that they are aware and they are cutting it? Make sure you have documentation of all conversations from now on and backups of your documentation, both digital and hard copy backups. Not to make a legal issue out of it, but just in case....

Comment: The first step would be to find out the current market rate. Maybe it's closer to 35$ and they made a honest mistake. Maybe it's closer to 60 and they are scumbags. Find out.

Comment: @nvoigt 50 is a genuine rate for developer position in Seattle WA.
Plus, how can I find the current market rate ?

Comment: Sorry, but we have no fortune-telling crystal balls. We don't know whether somebody can be trusted or not. We don't know if anybody is taking advantage or not. We don't know which path will be the better option for your future career.

Comment: You have way too much text and way too many questions here and those questions are unanswerable here. We don't have a crystal ball and we can't tell you what to do. Check [tour] and [help] for details on what are good questions to ask on this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have to skip most of your questions, as the answers would be primarily fortune-telling.

> That's what they would have done if it wasn't an urgent hiring, right ?

No. There is no such thing as a hiring process that prevents hiring in urgent cases.

If someone needs to be hired, this can be accomplished in a few days, no matter how the normal hiring process looks like. If someone tells you that you cannot work for them, but for some other company that works for them, it means that the scope of your intended work is very limited at the moment, likely to a single project that is running late.

This is a temporary agency worker situation, where you will be kept by company C for as long as they can lend to you another company and fire you if the prospects are not good. As you were only hired because you could be lent immediately to another company, there is a fair chance they will fire you immediately again, instead of looking for other companies who might want you.

> How and to whom should I approach for answer?

You should direct questions regarding your salary to company C, questions regarding a permanent position at company A to someone at company A.

Comment: Very well explained

Comment: @JohnHammond 
I have edited the post and believe it to be as per requirement. Could you please remove it from [on-hold] ?

Comment: @vinegar I don't have any special powers here. If you have edited your question after the close-vote, it automatically gets a reopen-flag which is again reviewed by multiple people. If those people still vote to let it stay closed, it stays closed.